# Search for statement not followed by other

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a code like this:

```
myType.DoSomething(myParams);
```

That should immediately be followed by this statement

```
anotherType.DoeSomethingDifferent(otherParams);
```

Is there a way on ReShaprer I can identify all those sources where the first statement is NOT followed by the second one? I tried to use the "Search With Pattern" command with the following:

```
$aVar$.DoSomething($args$)
```

However this only lists all usages of exactly that method on `myType`. I need those usages that arte not followed by the second statement. Is this possible?

EDIT: Of course I could simply add the two lines into one single method. However there MIGHT be scenarios in which writing the first line without the second one is usefull. I simply want to grab those.